# Popup DatePicker for EditText

Tags: android, android-datepicker

Been trying to look at other questions on here regarding DatePickers popping up for `EditText` but I've had problems getting it working.

I've seen examples where you can use `setOnClickListener` or `setOnTouchListener`, which one would be the best?

Also I've seen a couple of different designs to the `DatePicker`, how do you change the design?

Below is my code so far, tried using code from the other examples but couldn't get it working.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * Created by MOS182 on 7/21/13.
 */
public class AddReminder extends Activity {

    TextView Title, Amount, PaymentDate, ReminderDate, ReminderTime;
    EditText eTitle, eAmount, ePaymentDate, eReminderDate, eReminderTime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reminders_dialog);
        initializeVariables();
    }



    private void initializeVariables()
    {
        Title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        Amount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAmount);
        PaymentDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPaymentDate);
        ReminderDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvReminderDate);
        ReminderTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvReminderTime);
        eTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
        eAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAmount);
        ePaymentDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPaymentDate);
        eReminderDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etReminderDate);
        eReminderTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etReminderTime);
    }


}
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html. check the docs it has code snippets. Also **how do you change the design** pls elaborate.

Comment: Did you tried DatePickerDialog?

Comment: @R9j I tried it when looking at other examples, couldn't get it working, like I didn't know how to set it up correctly

Comment: @Raghunandan I've seen different designs. 1. http://www.htcdev.com/images/uploads/DatePicker.png 2. http://kollerie.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/android_datepicker_widget.png

Comment: @MOS182 you can use different themes. check the pickers doc.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I have used **setOnClickListener** `EditText` method to show a `DatePicker`.

And then in xml file set EditText property `android:focusable="false"`.So that you can avoid focus and virtual keyboards.

```
yourEditText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //To show current date in the datepicker
            Calendar mcurrentDate=Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog mDatePicker=new DatePickerDialog(**YourActivityName**.this, new OnDateSetListener() {                  
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                      
                    /*      Your code   to get date and time    */
                }
            },mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            mDatePicker.setTitle("Select date");                
            mDatePicker.show();  }
    });
```

try this one...comment your thoughts...thanks..

Comment: How did you show the DatePicker once you called the setOnClickListener method?

Comment: Only one error, "cannot resolve symbol 'AddNewMessage' ", how do I get rid of this error?

Comment: Please change "AddNewMessage" to your activity name.I have edited my answer.

Comment: Many thanks for helping out! This is the only code I had to add to get it working - ePaymentDate.setText("" + selectedday + "/" + selectedmonth + "/" + selectedyear);

Comment: month starts from 0 to 11 so when you set to EditText just add one with (selectedmonth+1) like this...And can youpls upvote this answer dude.

Comment: Yeah I realised that when I was testing it, so I put ' selectedmonth = selectedmonth + 1; ' before that line of code

Comment: Plain and Simple. Like it.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* create calndar object */  
  Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
/* find textview*/
date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stdate);
/* and copy the fallowing code*/
final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
              @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                String myFormat = "dd/MMM/yyyy"; //In which you need put here
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.UK);

                date.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));

            }

        };


        date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, datePickerListener, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

For older APIs ie I still try to support 16 ... so:

From http://javapapers.com/android/android-datepicker/

You can use a DialogFragment that implements DatePickerDialog as exampled:

```
public static class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    // Thanks to -> http://javapapers.com/android/android-datepicker/
    EditText mEditText;
    public SelectDateFragment(EditText mEditText){
        this.mEditText = mEditText;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
        populateSetDate(mEditText, yy, mm+1, dd);
    }
}

public void selectDate() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment(editText);
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
}
public static void populateSetDate(EditText mEditText, int year, int month, int day) {
    mEditText.setText(month+"/"+day+"/"+year);
}
```

In your activity set you editText value as required:

```
private EditText editText; 
//...
```

Attach the onclick listener:

```
    editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            selectDate();

        }
    });
```